# Is there any way to move your application to Beta from Production (Live) in Playstore

Tags: android, react-native

I have uploaded my app in production. Now, I am trying to withdraw it to the beta version. 
Has anyone any idea

Answer (score 0):

Update the app, and release on Beta, it will override the production app